# Another word for "private"

Tags: word-request

I am writing about poker tournaments. I need to express the idea that there are two types of tournaments - open (everyone can participate) and the tournament where there are certain terms for participation (promo code, invitation, etc.)

What's the right word for that second kind? Restricted, private, exclusive, limited? I can't find the right word for that one.

Answer (score 10):

*Closed* may be the word that you are looking for.

> The descriptor "open" is used in a number of sports, and especially in golf, to describe a tournament that is "open" — in theory to all — rather than being **closed**, i.e., one that is restricted to a particular group.

[Wikipedia: Open golf tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_golf_tournament)

Answer (score 10):

**Exclusive**

*"belonging only to the one person, unit, or group name"*

Answer (score 7):

If the specific terms is an invitation, then you may use "by invitation only":

> only open to people who have been invited. The event is *by invitation only*. ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by%20invitation%20only))

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest "invitational" as used in tennis and golf 
https://www.thoughtco.com/invitational-golf-tournament-1560888 - you and some others ( who all meet some conditions ) have been invited to play by a hosting entity; but another possibility is "qualified" you have met some number of conditions to allow your play.

Comment: Just to note, "open invitational" is a thing.